# How To Get Raw Date Number?

Tags: javascript, date

In my application, I am using my application to retrieve the date information from the server. e.g:1533675600000.
How do I get today's `raw date` number in this way? Every day, I want to refresh this daily `raw date` information and show only the information that matches the date of that day on my screen. So I ask you, how do I convert the date information I received with the `new Date ()` function to the `raw form of numbers` in this way?

Comment: cast it back to Date object with `new Date(1533675600000)`

Comment: @AlekseySolovey The new date that I created should be just numbers or I should be able to transform it. That's wrong, that can't be the solution.

Comment: @Fatih, you can use new Date(myDate).getTime() to get 'numeric' date.  Use a date pipe in your html to format it e.g. {{myDate | date:'dd-MMM-yyyy;}}

Comment: @Farasi78 Unfortunately. I have not been able to explain the situation. I have a date information and format is: 1533675600000. I want to compare it to the current date with this format but when I try to do it with newDate () this is invalid because the newDate format is not the same as my date format from the server.

Comment: @Fatih cast both of them with Date object then: `new Date(1533675600000).getTime()  == new Date(current_date).getTime()`

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming by **raw date** you mean **Epoch time**.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time):

> Epoch time is a system for describing a point in time, defined as an
>   approximation of the number of seconds that have elapsed since
>   00:00:00 Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), Thursday, 1 January 1970.

[Date.now()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) method returns the number of milliseconds elapsed since January 1, 1970 00:00:00 UTC.

To get current Epoch time, simply convert the value returned from `Date.now()` into seconds like

```
Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000); // current time in seconds
```

Then perform any comparisons you want with this value.